# Hide multiple labels using loop

Tags: vb.net, label, hide

How can I hide multiple `Label` controls using a loop?  I have tried doing so with the following code:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 14
    Dim lbl = Controls("Label" & i)
    lbl.Visible = False
Next
```

But it's not working for me.  When the code executes, it throws a `NullReferenceException` on the `lbl.Visible = False` line.

Comment: What happens when you run that code? Does it err? Does it _seem_ to do  nothing? Have you debugged to see exactly what it _does_ do? Where is your example of the label name format (other than your construction that isn't working)? And so on... in short, please improve this question.

Comment: I have 14 Label Boxes in my form. I want to hide all these label boxes when i  click a button. Its name is Label1, Label2, Label3....... Label14.

Comment: As long as `Option Strict` is `Off`, the code you have shown should work, so please explain what happens when you use that code?  Does it fail to compile?  Does it throw a runtime exception?  Does it simply have no affect when the code runs?

Comment: It shows NullReferance Exception was unhandled, Object variable or With block variable not set. on line lbl.Visible = False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my code like this.. Its working now.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 14
        Dim lbl = EMPGBDATA.Controls("Label" & i.ToString())
        If lbl IsNot Nothing Then
            lbl.Visible = False
        End If
    Next
```

EMPGBDATA is a GroupBox in my form.. All these labels in EMPGBDATA.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you get that error is probably because you have less that 14 labels on your form.  I'm guessing that it's `Label14`, or even a label with a smaller number, doesn't exist.  Check that.

Also, if you want to hide all of the labels on your form, then it would be better to do something like this:

```
 For Each lbl As Label In Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
     lbl.Visible = False
 Next
```

**After your comments:**

Which version of Visual Studio are you using?  `OfType` works in both VS2008 and 2010.  Maybe not in earlier versions...

Another way to do it is like this:

```
For Each cnt As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf cnt Is Label Then
        cnt.Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Error : 'OfType' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection'

Comment: `OfType` is a LINQ extension method, so, if you are using LINQ, that method will work.

Comment: `For Each cnt As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf cnt Is Label Then
        cnt.Visible = False
    End If
Next` -- This code is working. But it Hides all the Labels. I want to hide only the particular 14 labels Label1, Label2, Label3,.... Label14.

Comment: I know, I already written that. Then you should follow Steven Doggart solution

Comment: I have similar problem, but I have 3 types of label, for rooms1+, description1+ and action1+.... how can I do this?

Comment: What you mean 3 types of label?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get a control from the `Form.Controls` collection by index like this:

```
Dim lbl As Control = Controls(100)
```

If no control by that index exists, it will immediately throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, as you would expect.  However, for some strange reason, whoever implemented the `ControlCollection` class decided that when you are trying to get a control by name, like this:

```
Dim lbl As Control = Controls("Label100")
```

If no control by that name exists, rather than throwing an exception, it simply returns `Nothing`.  Therefore, to be safe, you should check to make sure a control was actually returned, like this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 14
    Dim lbl = Controls("Label" & i.ToString())
    If lbl IsNot Nothing Then
        lbl.Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

Checking if `lbl` is `Nothing`, like that, will stop the `NullReferenceException` from being thrown.  However, that doesn't explain why it's returning `Nothing` in the first place.

There are two reasons I can think of why it may not be finding your control:

- You have the wrong control name.  You are looking for a control with the name "Label1", but you may be mistaken and that may not be the actual name of the control.  It's possible, for instance, for the control's name to be different than the variable name that references it.  To know for sure, inspect the value of `Label1.Name` to see what its name actually is.
- The `Controls` property on your form has been overloaded so it's not calling the base property.  To fix that, you could specify `MyBase.Controls` instead of simply `Controls`.

Comment: `For i As Integer = 1 To 14
    Dim lbl = Controls("Label" & i.ToString())
    If lbl IsNot Nothing Then
        lbl.Visible = False
    End If
Next` My friend nothing  happened with this code..There is no error in the code. But my 14 label boxes still there....

Comment: Check your labels' names. How you have name them. This code will work only if you know exactly the names that your labels have

Comment: Is there a `Label1` property on your form?

Comment: Yea... I have more labels in my form. But I need to hide only fourteen labels with name Label1, Label2, Label3,.... Label14. All these labels in a GroupBox.

Comment: Ah, yes, we'll that's the problem. I should have thought of that!